# Does laravel necessarily need proc_open() and passthru() enabled?

Tags: php, laravel-5, shared-hosting, php-extension

I am installing laravel on a shared hosting at KVC webhost. It shows a blank page. I checked the log and it says that the proc_open() and passthru() aren't enabled on my server which is causing the errors.
I have contacted my webhosting for solutions but they can only enable on VPS. 
Any other solutions?

Comment: I feel your pain. I had endless hassles with my ex-host. Eventually I moved to Digital Ocean and that was a breeze. Do you have to particularly stay with with your current host?

Comment: I have already paid them uptil 2017 :(

Comment: Are you trying to install it using composer or copying the files to the server?

Comment: I used softaculous to install Laravel in a directory, and had to change all files. Also have been facing issues regarding queues and many artisan commands. Most probably will shift to Digital Ocean!

Comment: hey, i might be hitting up late on this but did you find any solution on this?

Comment: Follow this link, it will help you to solve problem. [prog_open() Solution](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/30054)

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be anything in a default Laravel application that requires `proc_open()` or `passthru()` to serve a site. These may be needed for commandline processes though.

Do a complete build the application locally (eg `composer install`), then deploy the files to the server.